# How to linearly boost the output of a Gaussian shaping amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, signal, pulse, linear

I have a pulse detection set up that takes in analog pulses (with relatively long tails, gamma spectroscopy). This pulse is sent into a shaping amplifier, that removes the tail, and shapes the pulse to a Gaussian, around 1 us duration. The output from this amplifier is then a pulse between 0-6V, and read out on an oscilloscope. The frequency of pulses to be detected is <0.1 MHz.

I would like to boost the output so that the 0-6V pulse is converted linearly to a 0-10V pulse. What are the options for doing linear pulse amplification?

Comment: What supplies are avail? what source impedance and load , any cables involved?

Comment: It sounds like you just want an amplifier with a gain of 10/6. Does that sound about right? And the bandwidth must be sufficient to reproduce a Guassian with a 1us duration? What is the output impedance of the shaping amplifier? It sounds like an op-amp circuit would work fine for this. Maybe a video amplifier.

Comment: Tristen, Do you need to retain the Gaussian shape of the pulse? (There is a fairly rapid transition taking place at the leading and trailing edges and these, if required to be retained, will set some specific requirements on the amplifier.) Or can you accept some differences in the resulting shape after the gain is applied? Also, what about the offset? May it also be shifted upward slightly? Or is there a requirement there, too? (I'd like to see a picture from the scope, too.)

Comment: @jonk The shaping amp has an adjustable DC offset and P/Z. The shape retention isn't necessary, as I'm just looking at the peak of the pulse. I can provide scope shots tomorrow. But all I'm really looking for is to boost the peak voltage from the pulse by a factor of 10/6 as a previous commenter said.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, this sounds right. I do not care that the Gaussian shape is retained. I just need the peak of the pulse to amplified by 10/6. The shape after the 10/6 amplification could be a square wave for all I care.

Comment: @TristenLee So this sounds much easier than I first imagined. If you E serious about the square wave then a schmitt trigger will work great.

Comment: @jonk Tristen needs to preserve amplitude. So schmitt trigger probably will not work. I think a 10 MHz BW video amp will do it.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks. I suppose when someone writes that a square wave is okay I imagine something else is also okay.

Answer (score 2):

A high speed opamp will work. This is the fastest that I have in my stash. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm6171.pdf Probably overkill.

It will pass a 1 \$\mu\$s squared pulse with good signal integrity, so a shaped pulse should be no problem.

This experiment has a gain of 2. You will need to reduce the value of R2 to get the 10/6 ratio that you desire.

You will want to add two 0.1 uF decoupling caps from the power pins to ground, close to the IC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4rxyw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yellow is the input, blue is the output.

[image]